# Join 2 tables, with filter and order by

Tags: mysql, sql, join

**I want to join these 2 tables:**

order_ticket_messages:

[image]

Sample data:

[image]

---

order_files:

[image]

Sample data:

[image]

---

The orderid must be the same, and I want to sort them ASC by date.
Not all the data must be included, but the id is required (and a way to see if it is a message or file).

I have no idea how to do this. It'll be something with a JOIN, but that's where my knowledge stops.

---

**Expected output:**

ID | MESSAGE | FILE | DATE

If it's a message, file will be NULL. If it's a file, message will be NULL.
(I can load the order data by the ID).

Comment: Do you need to have 1 row per orderid containing information about ticket_message & files ?

Comment: @Orkad If possible yes, or just the IDs and a way to see if it is a file or message.

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: @forpas Added to my question.

Comment: Are there unique constraints on the order IDs in the tables? Otherwise you could have multiple messages and multiple files per order, in which case a join would make little sense, as combine each message with each file (row 1 = message 1 + file 1, row 2 = message 1 + file 2, row 3 = message 2 + file 1, row 4 = message 2 + file 2, ...).

Comment: Please show sample data and the related expected output.

Comment: Are you looking for one single order and the result is a list of all its messages and files?

Comment: In both tables, only the id is UNIQUE. Added the data. Expected output was already in my question.

And yes, 1 order, and a list of the messages and files, sorted by the date.

Comment: Next time, please don't use images, but paste the data as plain text. Please see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question on this. Then, `ID | MESSAGE | FILE | DATE` is not an expected output, except for the case you don't want any rows to get selected. So, next time, please show sample data (say two orders, each with two messages and two files) and the expected output (e.g. four rows for the first order). Please see my answer on how to show a table (for the sample rows and the expected output) in a stackoverflow request.

Comment: As you can see, you've got answers with queries selecting very different result sets. This has happened, because you didn't explain the task well enough. What is "The orderid must be the same" supposed to mean exactly? Next time, take more time to properly explain what you want. Choosing sample data carefully and showing the expected output rows will help a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to select messages and files for one order. That is two separate queries, one getting the messages, one getting the files. You want the union of their result sets.

### Query

```
select id, message, null as file, date from order_ticket_messages where order_id = 1
union all
select id, null as message, file, date from order_files where order_id = 1
order by date;
```

### Sample output

```
+----+-------------+-----------+---------------------+
| ID | MESSAGE     | FILE      | DATE                |
+----+-------------+-----------+---------------------+
| 1  | Omshrijving |           | 2020-07-23 14:47:18 |
| 2  | Dat kan     |           | 2020-07-23 15:03:08 |
| 24 |             | 38328.png | 2020-08-02 16:22:38 |
| 25 |             | fud82.png | 2020-08-02 16:23:29 |
+----+-------------+-----------+---------------------+
```

Comment: Works perfect, and very short! Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

What you describe can be achieved with `UNION ALL` and not a `JOIN`:

```
select m.id, m.message, null file, m.date 
from order_ticket_messages m
where exists (select 1 from order_files where orderid = m.orderid)
union all
select f.id, null, f.file, f.date 
from order_files f
where exists (select 1 from order_ticket_messages where orderid = f.orderid)
order by date
```

Or if you want to keep the messages and files with the same `orderid` together:

```
select id, message, file, date
from (
  select m.id, m.message, null file, m.date, m.orderid 
  from order_ticket_messages m
  where exists (select 1 from order_files where orderid = m.orderid)
  union all
  select f.id, null, f.file, f.date, f.orderid 
  from order_files f
  where exists (select 1 from order_ticket_messages where orderid = f.orderid)
) t
order by orderid, date
```

Comment: Nice! What is the difference between the 1st and 2nd query?

Comment: In the 1st query the results are sorted only by date. So rows with the same orderid may not be together if the dates are different.

Comment: If you want all the orderids from both tables even the ones that don't exist in the other table you can remove both WHERE clauses.